# how to link a created icon in a body field to another field?

Tags: 8, entities, navigation

With the fontawesome module I can easly create in CKEditor fontawesome icons in a body field. I want to link this icon to a telephone field (field_call_me)

A more specific example:
If I created a whatsapp icon in a bodyfield. How could I link this to a telephone field?

## My steps:

## I installed:

`$ composer require 'drupal/fontawesome:^2.0'`
`$ drupal module:install fontawesome`

## I created a contenttype

`admin/structure/types`
name: call me
description: add whatsapp number

## I add telephone field

label: call me
default value: +12345678
machine name: field_call_me

I tried to link it with link icon module. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need not add (should not be, rather) icon field to content type. You can display the whatsapp icon though css, it would be a matter of adding 
`<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>` before showing the phone number. You might want to create a `field--node--field-name--content-type.html.twig` file for controlling the display aspects for the field.